# Disabled button based on React input fields not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm trying to enable a button, after two fields have been selected, but for some reason, I have to click on the second field twice to trigger it to enabled. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

So to confirm, when I click on a price and when I click on donateTo field, it is setting state correctly, however it doesn't enable the bottom at the bottom until I have clicked one of the fields a third or fourth time.

```js
const DonateBox = ({ goToPayment }) => {
  const [price, setPrice] = useState('');
  const [donateTo, setDonateTo] = useState('');
  const [isProgressDisabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);

  const handleSetDonateTo = (e) => {
    setDonateTo(e.target.value);
    disabledCheck();
  };

  const handlePriceClick = (e) => {
    setPrice(e.target.value);
    disabledCheck();
  };

  const handleGoToPayment = () => {
    goToPayment('paymentbox');
  };

  const disabledCheck = () => {
    if (price && donateTo) {
      setDisabled(false);
    }
    console.log(isProgressDisabled);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.donateBox}>
        <p className={styles.heading}>
          Give through the most effective platform for good.
        </p>
        <p className={styles.subheading}>
          100% goes to the causes listed in the article here. You are one click
          away!
        </p>
        <div className={styles.itemList}>
          <label className={styles.labelWrapper}>
            <input
              type="radio"
              className={styles.customRadio}
              value="cause"
              onClick={handleSetDonateTo}
              checked={donateTo === 'cause'}
            />
            <span>Donate to Cause</span>
          </label>
          <label className={styles.labelWrapper}>
            <input
              type="radio"
              className={styles.customRadio}
              value="charity"
              onClick={handleSetDonateTo}
              checked={donateTo === 'charity'}
            />
            <span>Donate to Charity</span>
          </label>
          <label className={styles.labelWrapper}>
            <input
              type="radio"
              className={styles.customRadio}
              value="goods"
              onClick={handleSetDonateTo}
              checked={donateTo === 'goods'}
            />
            <span>Donate to Goods</span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.priceList}>
          <label
            className={`${styles.priceLabel} ${
              price === '25' ? `${styles.selected}` : ''
            }`}
          >
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="25"
              className={styles.priceInput}
              onClick={handlePriceClick}
              value="25"
            />
            $25
          </label>
          <label
            className={`${styles.priceLabel} ${
              price === '50' ? `${styles.selected}` : ''
            }`}
          >
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="50"
              className={styles.priceInput}
              onClick={handlePriceClick}
              value="50"
            />
            $50
          </label>
          <label
            className={`${styles.priceLabel} ${
              price === '75' ? `${styles.selected}` : ''
            }`}
          >
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="75"
              className={styles.priceInput}
              onClick={handlePriceClick}
              value="75"
            />
            $75
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button
        className={styles.largeButton}
        onClick={handleGoToPayment}
        disabled={isProgressDisabled}
      >
        Add Card Details
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default DonateBox;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @adesurirey's suggestion, this is the perfect scenario for [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

When the variable(s) inside of the dependency array are changed, the code in `useEffect` is invoked.

Meaning, you can automatically invoke the `disabledCheck` if `price` or `donateTo` are changed. This way you don't have to remember to call `disabledCheck` within the handlers.

**Edit** another excellent thing about `useEffect` in a scenario like this is that you know for sure `disabledCheck` is invoked only *after* state is changed.  Since mutating state is async, it is possible that `disabledCheck` was running before state was actually updated.

Think of `useEffect` like the callback function within `setState` (on class based components)..

```js
// Class based comparison...
// You know for sure `disabledCheck` is only called *after* 
// state has been updated
setState({ 
  some: 'newState' 
}, () => disabledCheck());
```

Demo:

```js
const { useState, useEffect, Fragment } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

const DonateBox = ({ goToPayment }) => {
  const [price, setPrice] = useState('');
  const [donateTo, setDonateTo] = useState('');
  const [isProgressDisabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);

  const handleSetDonateTo = (e) => {
    setDonateTo(e.target.value);
    // disabledCheck();
  };

  const handlePriceClick = (e) => {
    setPrice(e.target.value);
    // disabledCheck();
  };

  const handleGoToPayment = () => {
    goToPayment('paymentbox');
  };

  const disabledCheck = () => {
    if (price !== '' && donateTo !== '') {
      setDisabled(false);
    }
    console.log(isProgressDisabled);
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    disabledCheck();
  }, [price, donateTo]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>
        <p>
          Give through the most effective platform for good.
        </p>
        <p>
          100% goes to the causes listed in the article here. You are one click
          away!
        </p>
        <div>
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              value="cause"
              onClick={handleSetDonateTo}
              checked={donateTo === 'cause'}
            />
            <span>Donate to Cause</span>
          </label>
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              value="charity"
              onClick={handleSetDonateTo}
              checked={donateTo === 'charity'}
            />
            <span>Donate to Charity</span>
          </label>
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              value="goods"
              onClick={handleSetDonateTo}
              checked={donateTo === 'goods'}
            />
            <span>Donate to Goods</span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="25"
              onClick={handlePriceClick}
              value="25"
            />
            $25
          </label>
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="50"
              onClick={handlePriceClick}
              value="50"
            />
            $50
          </label>
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="75"
              onClick={handlePriceClick}
              value="75"
            />
            $75
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button
        onClick={handleGoToPayment}
        disabled={isProgressDisabled}
      >
        Add Card Details
      </button>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

const App = () => <DonateBox />

render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome! Glad I was able to help. One last thing, which I also updated in my answer, but another excellent thing about `useEffect` in a scenario like this is that you know for sure `disabledCheck` is invoked only *after* state is changed.  Since mutating state is async, it is possible that `disabledCheck` was running before state was actually updated.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `onChange` events on your inputs instead of `onClick`

```
<input
  type="radio"
  name="75"
  className={styles.priceInput}
  onChange={handlePriceClick}
  value="75"
/>
```